# How to get the last start time for an ASP.NET app?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, datetime

How to get the last time the current ASP.NET app was initiated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well I guess,create a static class with a static consructor assigning a property to `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: It may work, but the result wasn't what I expected. It seems that the app can be recycled if it isn't used much.

Comment: yes this is true, the app is recycled if not used, and the static disappear. Next time a call arrives a new application is started and initialized, so the static will reflect this new date

Comment: You can disable the automatic recycling, check out the app pool settings.

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to forego an extra variable, I think this will give you the last time the IIS worker process (a.k.a. application pool) was restarted:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime
```

I use it to set cacheability because the page is based on content that I only dynamically generate on application startup:

```
Response.Cache.SetLastModified(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime);
```

It is possible to stop/start individual websites within an application pool / worker process, but I infer from [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/247425/what-is-the-difference-between-iisreset-recycle-refresh-and-restart) that doing so will not recreate static application objects, so I gather that the date associated with the worker process is probably the most useful date here.

Keep in mind also that a static application variable created on application startup will actually often times give you *the time the application was first visited.*  It is possible the worker process was started much earlier, and that brings into mind phrases like "IIS application warm up" and "IIS application autostart" and another discussion on when static fields are initialized in general.  What you choose might depend on whether or not you're interested in the last worker process recycle time or if you're interested in the time other static members were computed.

Comment: Keep in mind that overwriting/updating application files *does not* cause the process to restart. The `w3wp` process stays the same. Alternative answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66409256/56621

Answer (score 6):

You can set a static field to `DateTime.Now` in `Application_Start` in Global.asax.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution:

```
public static readonly DateTime StartupTime = DateTime.Now;
```

**I would strongly warn anyone from using `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime`**

When you update application files, the ASP.NET app is *hot-reloaded within the same process*. The App-Domain is being reloaded BUT `w3wp` process stays the same. Keep that in mind.