# How Long has my ASP.Net Web Service Been Running?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

Within a web service I would like to tell how long it's been running. It seems like there should be a simple way to do this, but apparently I'm Googling the wrong search term since I'm not coming up with anything.

Comment: you could add some editable file that in constructor =+ time from session depending on datetime.now

Comment: ta.speot.is: Yes it is, thanks for pointing me there.

Comment: answer linked by @ta.speot.is is the way if you need to know how long app was running, if you need timing for whole process (that may be hosting multiple sites) you should be able to get this info from process's information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did (similar to some of the ideas that [ta.speot.is](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242520/ta-speot-is) pointed out is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994104/how-to-get-the-last-start-time-for-an-asp-net-app)). Thanks

```
Public Sub New()
    if (Application("ServiceStarted") == null) { // Run only first time
        Application.Lock()
        Application("ServiceStarted") = Now()
        Application.UnLock()
    }
End Sub
```

Comment: I think there is really not much reason for locking - if you end up Application created at the same time by runtime something is going wrong already... And reading does not need any locks since it will always happen later...